# How to debug "NoMethodError" in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the error

```
NoMethodError in Styles#new undefined method 'styles_path' for <Class:0x00000006288268>:0x0000000632ca20
```

It works perfectly well if I do not have the `form_for` option and let us say replace the entire snippet with Hello World.

new.html.erb file code in the app/views/styles folder

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="well col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <%= form_for @style do |f|%>
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
      <%= f.submit 'Create style' , class: 'btn btn-success' %>
    <%end%>
  </div>
</div>
```

I defined the styles controller as:

```
class StylesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @style = Style.new
  end

end
```

The routes file has the following snippet

```
  resources :styles, only: [:new,:show]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `form_for` you are POSTing the form on `styles_path` (POST) to create a new style, however, in your `routes.rb` you have mentioned only `new` and `show`. You need to add one for `create` as well as you need to add a new action named as `create` in your controller too.

routes.rb

```
resources :styles, only: [:new, :show, :create]
```

controller:

```
class StylesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @style = Style.new
  end

  def create
    # your code
  end

end
```

**Recommendation:** You should [read this](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-first-form)